# Treetop grammar line continuation

Tags: ruby, parsing, bnf, treetop

I'm trying to create a grammar for a language like the following

```
someVariable = This is a string, I know it doesn't have double quotes
anotherString = This string has a continuation _
      this means I can write it on multiple line _
      like this
anotherVariable = "This string is surrounded by quotes"
```

What are the correct Treetop grammar rules that parse the previous code correctly?

I should be able to extract the following values for the three variables

- This is a string, I know it doesn't have double quotes
- This string has a continuation this means I can write it on multiple line like this
- This string is surrounded by quotes

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define the sequence "_\n" as if it was a single white-space character, and ensure that you test for that before you accept an end-of-line, your VB-style line continuation should just drop out. In VB, the newline "\n" is not white-space per se, but is a distinct statement termination character. You probably also need to deal with carriage returns, depending on your input character processing rules. I would write the white-space rule like this:

```
rule white
  ( [ \t] / "_\n" "\r"? )+
end
```

Then your statement rule looks like this:

```
rule variable_assignment
  white* var:([[:alpha:]]+) white* "=" white* value:((white / !"\n" .)*) "\n"
end
```

and your top rule:

```
rule top
    variable_assignment*
end
```

Your language doesn't seem to have any more apparent structure than that.

Comment: Clifford, I believe you've put me on the right track but I think it would be useful if you could write all the rules to make that code parse. I will then accept your answer. I've edited the question to fix the mistake you've pointed out.

Comment: Note that I didn't address your double-quote situation because you didn't define that part of the problem very well. But this should get you going, it's easy to add quoting.

Comment: Thanks Clifford. What are var: and value: ?

Comment: They're labels, Documented here: http://cjheath.github.io/treetop/semantic_interpretation.html